# Method to find simulation envelopes for association (pair correlation) between adults and juveniles using homogeneous Thomas process in R

Tags: r, spatstat

I have marked ppp object (shp) that consist of ; x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate, growth ("adult", "juvenile","sapling").

I found simulation envelopes for association (using pair correlation function) between adults and juveniles using homogeneous Poisson process.

```
aj1<-envelope(shp,pcfcross,nsim = 199,i = "adult", j = "juvenile",savefuns=TRUE)
```

Now I want to find the same thing using homogeneous Thomas process. So I fit a homogeneous Thomas process to a point pattern object using

```
fit1 <- kppm(shp ~1, "Thomas",method ="palm").
```

Then I tried to find simulation envelopes using

```
aj2<-envelope(fit1,pcfcross,nsim = 199,i = "adult", j = "juvenile",savefuns=TRUE)
```

But this did not work. If anyone has any suggestion or any alternative method to find simulation envelopes for association (using pair correlation function) between adults and juveniles using homogeneous Thomas process, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

From [Spatial Lecture Note](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Francois.Coeurjolly/documents/lecture3.pdf), is the following example helpful

```
require('spatstat')
data("redwood")
X <- redwood
plot(X)
plot(envelope(X))
fit <- kppm(X, ~1, "Thomas")
plot(fit)
plot(envelope(fit))
```

[image: Example of Thomas envelope]

Comment: This is only for unmarked point patterns. It gives no insight into the association between different types of points.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think any generic software to estimate multitype Poisson cluster models exists. We hope to add such functionality to `spatstat` in the not too distant future (but realistically many months from now). I know of some people that have worked on this and you might ask them for code. I think the paper

> Jalilian, A., Guan, Y., Mateu, J. and Waagepetersen, R. (2014)
>   Multivariate product-shot-noise Cox models, Biometrics, 71, 1022-1033.

may be very relevant for you and you can ask the authors whether they have any code you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `kppm` does not handle marked point patterns. You would have got an error message about "cannot handle marked point patterns" when you tried to fit the model `kppm(shp ~ 1, "Thomas", method="palm")`.

This functionality will be added to `spatstat` sometime in 2016.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Is there another package in R to handle this marked point pattern.